# MKCircle - Stroke Width equivilant to meters

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I have a MKCircle. I would like to be able to set a stroke width equivilant to meters not points. So that I can draw an overlay with both radius in meters of a stroke width in meters.

I understand that the points to meters relationship changes whenever the map is zoomed. I have a very low annotation count (1) right now so removing and readding it on zoom should be OK if I can figure out a way to calculate the desired stroke width in points for a meter distance at a given map state.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is whether you really want to do this: the line could wind up being invisibly thin if the user zooms out.

The only way I can see to do it is to create an appropriately-sized MKCoordinateRegion using [`MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance) and then use MKMapView's [`convertRegion:toRectToView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/convertRegion%3atoRectToView%3a) to convert it to a CGRect, from which you can read out the width/height to calculate the appropriate line width.

Comment: I have a floor of 1.0 so that it is not invisible when zoomed out.